Mobile version of website homepage not updating to reflect changes
I'm having similar issues with my website https://www.utdtradingpartners.com/
I made some changes on the home page and other pages of the website. Everything is working fine on laptop but the homepage for mobile version doesn't reflect the new changes. The inner pages of the website on mobile also work fine, but home page doesn't update on mobile. I do have a caching plugin installed on the site, but when clearing cache, the website stopped working so I had to restore it. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!
I added some new sections to the website home page and footer which is working fine on laptop but the changes ate not being reflected on mobile homepage. They are being reflected on mobile inner pages of the website.

The question doesn't seem to specify what software/technology you are using for your HTTP server. Neither is the plugin software specified in the question. How are you clearing the cache? When you do that, what error do you get? Please start by editing the question to add tags that reflect the technology.
